# How to trigger the PR Lint Github app on any PR

Tags: github, github-actions, github-app

I have installed the `PRLint` Github app (https://github.com/ewolfe/prlint) on my GitHub repository

As required, I have some PRLint configuration in `.github/prlint.json`

prlint.json

```
{
 "title": [
{
  "pattern": "^(build|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|style|test):\\s",
  "message": "PR title needs to be prefixed with a topic"
}
],}
```

However when I'm creating any PR, this is not triggering the PRLint to check if the PR is meeting the requirements or not

Under the repository "branch protection rules" I opted to pass all status checks to pass.

[image]

*Please note I tried to look for PRLint in search box but nothing was found.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found an alternate app for it that served the purpose

## PRLint Reloaded

https://github.com/maor-rosenfeld/prlint-reloaded

My `~/.github/prlint.json`

```
{
 "title": [
  {
   "pattern": "^(build|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|style|test):\\s",
   "message": "PR title needs to be prefixed with a topic"
  }
 ]
}
```

Repository Settings

[image]

That's it! **:)**